# How can I debug/test my custom migrate module?

Tags: 8, migrations

I've written a custom migrate module in Drupal 8. (Based on these instructions: https://github.com/wunderkraut/migrate_source_example/)

The migration reads data from a XML file with the "migrate_source_xml" extension and should write/update the data in a node.

I have a yml config file in /config/install/ and some logic in /src/migrate/source/

When I run the migration with "drush mi --all" I get the correct values in my prepareRow function. Unfortunately, no nodes were create and I get the message "Processed 0 items (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored)"

With the prepareRow function I'm able to stop the script at this position. But how can I debug the script afterwards? Does exist a postImport function or something similar?

How do you test your D8 migrations?

Thank you very much for your inputs!

Answer (score 2):

The place you want to step through is the while loop in MigrateExecutable::import() - this is where each source row is received after prepareRow(), run through the processing pipeline ($this->processRow), and saved to the destination plugin ($destination->import()).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tested the migration and I've found the problem. In SourcePluginBase.php#L239 the if statement fails because of the aboveHighwater and rowChanged check (both are NULL). Therefore, the "currentRow" value is NULL and the import fails at MigrateExecutable.php#L217
Do you know what the reason could be?

Comment: Is `($destination->import())` still relevant?  I can't find it in my code base 
(Migrate 8.x.4.2)

Comment: It's still in the latest 8.x development branch (8.9.x): https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.9.x/core/modules/migrate/src/MigrateExecutable.php#L226